# MySQL comparing marketing data month to month

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a client who doesn't want to use a dashboard and wants us to input their monthly KPI's into an Excel spreadsheet (I know, I know).

The part that's giving me a bit of trouble is comparing the marketing data month to month and inputting into rows under each KPI for the current month, titled '% Change':

[image]

So far this is the code I have for that part alone. What should I do?

```
SELECT
    MonthName,
    campaigns,
    SUM( spend ) AS Spend,
    SUM( clicks ) AS Clicks,
    SUM( clicks/ impressions ) AS CTR,
    SUM( Demo_Request_Thank_You ) As Conversions,
    SUM( spend/Demo_Request_Thank_You ) AS CPA,
    SUM( Demo_Request_Thank_You /c licks ) AS CVR
    COUNT( id ) AS orders,
    SUM( total_price ) AS revenue
FROM
    Dummy_data_warehouse.Dummy_DS3_Reporting_Table
WHERE
    MonthName IN (2,3)
    AND
    DATE_PART('year', created_at) = 2022
GROUP BY
    month
ORDER BY
    month ASC
```

Also...

```
CASE
    WHEN Spend * 100/(SELECT SUM(val) FROM Scores) as '% Change'
    WHEN clicks * 100/(SELECT SUM(val) FROM Scores) as '% Change'
```

Comment: Please share some sample data and desired output.

Comment: Share as textual code, not as a picture..

Comment: Your query's `WHERE` can be simplified to `WHERE ( created_at >= '2022-02-01' AND created_at < '2022-04-01' )` - it should also run much faster as it plays nicer with indexes (as it's as straightforward range query... also assuming you have the `created_at` column indexed), whereas you should avoid using `DATE_PART` as it isn't normally SARGable (at least not without extra effort).

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? What is the significance of the `CASE WHEN` code below your query?

Comment: Where is the `month` column defined? How does it compare to `monthName`? What is the difference between `created_at`, `month`, and `monthName`? (And why do you have so many seemingly redundant columns?)

Comment: **Your current query, as-is, is invalid** and doesn't even execute: your `GROUP BY` only has `month`, but your `SELECT` has `monthName` and `campaigns` (plural??!) as _group key columns_. If it works for you then it's because you're [using the horribly ancient MySQL 5.x release which permits invalid `GROUP BY` queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) which invariably produces incorrect and/or meaningless results. You need to fix that.

Comment: `SUM( clicks/ impressions ) AS CTR` should be `SUM( SUM( clicks ) / impressions ) AS CTR` btw - and you need think about what should happen when `impressions = 0`.

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

- To compare data between (ordered) rows you need to use [the `LAG` and/or `LEAD` window-functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html).
- I assume you're using a modern version of MySQL which supports `LAG` and `LEAD`, as opposed to the *zombie version* 5.x, which does not support `LAG` and `LEAD`, in which case you'll need to do the row comparison logic in Excel instead of directly in MySQL.

  - That's not necessarily a bad thing: Excel PowerQuery is actually pretty cool and very expressive.
- BTW, because your query uses `/` division inside an aggregate function (e.g. `SUM( clicks/ impressions )`) you'll likely run into divide-by-zero issues. My answer below should mitigate that.

Anyway, take your current query and convert it to a CTE (because inner-queries are passé now) and then use the windowing functions there.

Like so:

```sql
/* This query uses ISO SQL syntax so it should work in all modern RDMBS, including MySQL 8. If you're running MySQL 5 then you are beyond help. */
WITH

-- Aggregates, part 1 (without any division operations)
agg1 AS (
    SELECT
        -- Grouping key columns:
        campaign,
        EXTRACT( YEAR  FROM created_at ) AS "year",
        EXTRACT( MONTH FROM created_at ) AS "month",

        -- Grouping aggregates:
        COUNT( id )                   AS orders,
        SUM( spend )                  AS spend,
        SUM( clicks )                 AS clicks,
        SUM( impressions )            AS impressions,
        SUM( Demo_Request_Thank_You ) AS conversions,
        SUM( total_price )            AS revenue
    FROM
        Dummy_data_warehouse.Dummy_DS3_Reporting_Table
    WHERE
        created_at >= '2022-02-01'
        AND
        created_at < '2022-04-01'
    GROUP BY
        campaign,
        EXTRACT( YEAR  FROM created_at ),
        EXTRACT( MONTH FROM created_at )
),

-- Aggregates, part 2.
-- Averages are calculated here inside CASE expressions to avoid divide-by-zero issues.
agg2 AS (

    SELECT
        -- Group key columns:
        campaign,
        "year",
        "month",

         -- Previously aggregated values:
        orders,
        spend,
        clicks,
        impressions,
        conversions,
        revenue,

        -- New averages:
        CASE impressions WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE ( clicks / impressions ) END AS ctr,
        CASE conversions WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE ( spend / conversions ) END AS cpa,
        CASE clicks      WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE ( conversions / clicks ) END AS cvr
    FROM
        agg1
),
-- Now use LAG to compare values between (sorted) rows.
-- You cannot use `ORDER BY` inside a CTE, instead the sorting ORDER BY criteria follows the window function.
rowComparisons AS (

    SELECT
        -- Group key columns:
        campaign,
        "year",
        "month",

         -- Previously aggregated values:
        orders,
        spend,
        clicks,
        impressions,
        conversions,
        revenue,

        -- Previously calculated averages:
        ctr,
        cpa,
        cvr
    
        -- LAG row comparisons:
        spend  - LAG( spend,  /*offset:*/ 1, /*defaultValue:*/ 0 ) OVER ( ORDER BY campaign, "year", "month" ) AS spendDiff,
        clicks - LAG( clicks, /*offset:*/ 1, /*defaultValue:*/ 0 ) OVER ( ORDER BY campaign, "year", "month" ) AS clicksDiff
    FROM
        agg2
)
-- Finally (outside the CTE), calculate the percentages from the previously calculated LAG results:
SELECT
    -- Group key columns:
    campaign,
    "year",
    "month",

    -- Previously aggregated values:
    orders,
    spend,
    clicks,
    impressions,
    conversions,
    revenue,

    -- Previously calculated averages:
    ctr,
    cpa,
    cvr,

    -- Previously calculated LAG values:
    spendDiff,
    clicksDiff,

    -- Percentage calculations (with divide-by-zero avoidance):
    CASE spend WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE (
        ( spendDiff  / spend  ) * 100
    ) END AS "Spend % Change",

    CASE spend WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE (
        ( clicksDiff / clicks ) * 100
    ) END AS "Clicks % Change"
FROM
    rowComparisons
ORDER BY
    campaign,
    "year",
    "month"
```

- If you're wondering why there's so much repetition in the above query (e.g. reuse of `EXTRACT` and having to have 4 separate CTEs for each *step*<sup>1</sup> of the calculation sequence that's because the ISO SQL language design committee's priorities are not aligned with those of the people who actually write SQL queries.

  - Personally I think they enjoy getting-off on our misery; [the entire ISO organization looks evil anyway](https://twitter.com/isostandards/status/1367138254470930434), which explains a lot.

##### (Footnote 1)

Those 4 steps being:

1. Group by campaign and year+month and calculate aggregate `SUM` values.
2. Perform arithmetic division `/` on non-zero values to get averages.
3. Use `LAG` to get delta-values (differences).
4. Convert the delta-values to percentage-differences.

##### (Footnote 2)

To be fair, the query *can* be condensed to fewer CTE steps, but that involves lots of repetition of column expressions...

```
WITH agg AS (
    SELECT
        -- Grouping key columns:
        campaign,
        EXTRACT( YEAR  FROM created_at ) AS "year",
        EXTRACT( MONTH FROM created_at ) AS "month",

        -- Grouping aggregates:
        COUNT( id )                   AS orders,
        SUM( spend )                  AS spend,
        SUM( clicks )                 AS clicks,
        SUM( impressions )            AS impressions,
        SUM( Demo_Request_Thank_You ) AS conversions,
        SUM( total_price )            AS revenue,

        CASE SUM( impressions )            WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE ( SUM( clicks )                 / SUM( impressions )            ) END AS ctr,
        CASE SUM( Demo_Request_Thank_You ) WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE ( SUM( spend )                  / SUM( Demo_Request_Thank_You ) ) END AS cpa,
        CASE SUM( clicks )                 WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE ( SUM( Demo_Request_Thank_You ) / SUM( clicks )                 ) END AS cvr
    FROM
        Dummy_data_warehouse.Dummy_DS3_Reporting_Table
    WHERE
        created_at >= '2022-02-01'
        AND
        created_at < '2022-04-01'
    GROUP BY
        campaign,
        EXTRACT( YEAR  FROM created_at ),
        EXTRACT( MONTH FROM created_at )
),
SELECT
    -- Group key columns:
    campaign,
    "year",
    "month",

        -- Previously aggregated values:
    orders,
    spend,
    clicks,
    impressions,
    conversions,
    revenue,

    -- Previously calculated averages:
    ctr,
    cpa,
    cvr
    
    -- LAG row comparisons:
    ( spend  - LAG( spend,  /*offset:*/ 1, /*defaultValue:*/ 0 ) OVER ( ORDER BY campaign, "year", "month" ) ) AS spendDiff,
    ( clicks - LAG( clicks, /*offset:*/ 1, /*defaultValue:*/ 0 ) OVER ( ORDER BY campaign, "year", "month" ) ) AS clicksDiff,

    -- Percentage calculations (with divide-by-zero avoidance):
    CASE spend WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE (
        (
            ( spend  - LAG( spend,  /*offset:*/ 1, /*defaultValue:*/ 0 ) OVER ( ORDER BY campaign, "year", "month" ) )
            / spend
        ) * 100
    ) END AS "Spend % Change",

    CASE clicks WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE (
        (
            ( clicks - LAG( clicks, /*offset:*/ 1, /*defaultValue:*/ 0 ) OVER ( ORDER BY campaign, "year", "month" ) )
            / clicks
        ) * 100
    ) END AS "Clicks % Change"
FROM
    agg
ORDER BY
    campaign,
    "year",
    "month"
```

That's just *ugly*.

Comment: Thank you so much! My apologies, I just saw this. I am working through trying it now.

Comment: I am currently using MySQL 8 and I have to find a way around LAG functions.